# Update textbox value into sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql

When im trying to update the textbox values into db.It throws me an exception "Invalid syntax near (value of the txtkey.text)" Can anyone Help

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=server1;Database=testdb;User Id=dev;password=sqlad@2006");
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_licensing(UserName,CompanyName,EmailId,LicenseKey) values ('" + txtUserName.Text + "','" + txtCompanyName.Text + "','" + txtEmailId.Text + "','"+ txtKey.Text + "'",con);
                con.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten closing bracket **)** in your query

Updated code for you :

```
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into
 tbl_licensing(UserName,CompanyName,EmailId,LicenseKey) values ('" + txtUserName.Text + "','" 
+ txtCompanyName.Text + "','" + txtEmailId.Text + "','"+ txtKey.Text + "')",con);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have started this "`values (`" but you never closed it. Check again.

It will be good  if you use parameterized query or stored procedure instead of directly writing query

You can check this article.

http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/parameterized-queries-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong in many ways. Use parameterized query and you will

- Avoid sql injection attacks
- You will
  not have to escape the data entered
  by user
- The performance of your
  queries will get better
- The code will be much easier to read, understand and refactor.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use SqlCommand with parameters is to fill the SqlCommand's Parameters collection with parameter names and values.

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).